# Am I obligated to make others pray?

Tags: salat, fard, wajib

Is it an obligation to instruct other Muslims to pray during salah times like duhr?

I'm asking if it is an obligation because honestly it is too difficult; sometimes and I'd rather just stay at home then go through something like that.

If it is fard/wajib for me, then how do I advise them?

Comment: What makes you think it is fard?

Comment: I meant compulsory so maybe wajib is a better word?

Answer (score 1):

As a Muslim you can advise someone or remind someone but you cannot make someone. Your job is to invite. If you have good intentions, use different methods to get people to pray then you have done your part. Sometimes your steadfastness is the best dawah.